# Chrome : "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

Running on Chrome I get this error message:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

This is the part of my code which is responsible for the request:

```
function wetter() {

  $.ajax({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    type: 'GET',
    url: '[here comes the url',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (data) {
      //content
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: is there any other code inside the block of the `success` function, that may be causing the issue

Comment: Probably doesn't like your `'Accept'`. What line did it tell you the error was on?

Comment: chrome tells me the error is in the json

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to make a jsonp request to a script that sends json, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12430198/unable-to-complete-the-getjson-request/12430328#12430328). You cant just drop a p after the json and expect it to work.

Comment: @DariaDuda that's suppose to happen, read up on [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) and [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)

Comment: @DariaDuda the only way this will work is if you use a browser that doesn't enforce same origin policy or you use a serverside proxy

Comment: But my project requirement is to use a webkit browser, so chrome or safari :(

Answer (score 1):

The datatype it's receiving is probably not what it expects. You may be returning a JSON object while the expected result is JSON with padding (JSONP). You can either try returning JSONP type data or change the datatype in your code above to JSON.

Comment: I have changed my function: $.getJSON('http://api.wetter.com/forecast/weather/city/DE0001516/project/fakultaetvierboard/cs/4e7d520eea090e2bb8a8a8c5fc981b12/output/json?callback=?' but it still doesn't work