# JavaScript REST Request without AJAX (omit JSONP)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, rest

I'm using JSONP to send a REST Request, and I can see the response (json) in the chrome dev tools but can't use the result because I'm getting the error ["unexpected token :"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046008/jsonp-request-returning-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token). As you can read in linked question, this is because a function is expected as response (i get json).

Because I can't modify the webservice I need to access the webservice without AJAX so I dont have those problems with "same origin policy" and can use normal json as the data type. Every Example I can find is using AJAX. Isn't there another possibility?

Comment: So, to clarify: the webservice does not have cross-origin response headers, it returns JSON (not a JSONP callback function) and it's from a different origin?

Comment: are you sure there's no query param you can pass (like "callback") to get it to wrap the response in a function call?

Comment: @SvenKeinath, reverse proxy time.

Comment: I cant change the webservice. Can I force the webservice to wrap the response by changing my request?

Comment: @Dagg Nabbit, Can you explain what that means or give me a link please? I don't know what to do with this information.

Comment: @SvenKeinath set up a server to forward requests to webservice and pass the responses back to the client. Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) is an easy way to set one up.