# JSONP returning "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

The problem is very similar to [json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936610/json-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) and [JSONP request returning error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046008/jsonp-request-returning-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

I tried to make a call to fetch Divvy data. I use JSONP because I don't want to use server for this simple front end app.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: 'http://divvybikes.com/stations/json',
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "handleData",
  success: function(){
  }
});
```

However, Chrome keeps alerting with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

The url http://divvybikes.com/stations/json alone works well in browser.
Also, the status code is 200 all the time.

Anybody can help?

Comment: Well, the problem is exactly the same as in these questions. Did you understand the answers there?

Comment: The url does not return JSONP, but plain JSON.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I totally understand. I have a callback handler available `function handleData(){}`, but still does not work.

Comment: @FelixKling the question is the same on "how to JSONP this url", but the problem is different. My problem is I already used JSONP to call the api, but still not working. The solution I want is a JSONP solution rather than go back to JSON solution with server side call.

Comment: But JSONP has to be supported by the server. If you don't control the server and change that, you cannot use JSONP. JSONP is not a silver bullet that magically circumvents the same-origin policy.

Comment: @FelixKling Boom! You are right. Probably their endpoint does not support JSONP request. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have omitted some of the code.

First, when Chrome give you that error, you can click on it in the console window and it will show you the exact line that the error is being thrown.

Also, it seems like your code is a little more verbose than it need be.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: "http://divvybikes.com/stations/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Add @Bergi is correct, that this is actually returning JSON not JSONP.

Comment: Yeah, I know this. Your code will not work. You need to specify a call back which is globally available by this JSONP request. The problem is I already have this, but not working.

Comment: jQuery should keep track of your callback for you and create the global, unless you want to override this.

Comment: Please see the documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  "pecify the callback function name for a JSONP request. This value will be used instead of the random name automatically generated by jQuery. It is preferable to let jQuery generate a unique name as it'll make it easier to manage the requests and provide callbacks and error handling."  Regardless,   it looks like the DivvyBikes service does not provide jsonp, so you cannot access it using an ajax request..

Answer (score 0):

The return type should be JSONP but its currently returning JSON

example

```
//JSON
{"name":"abc","id":0}

//JSONP format
func({"name":"def","id":1});
```

also ensure that the JSON returned is valid.

Comment: Would you like to make an example based on my code?

Answer (score -2):

Copy the returned json.
Open http://jsonlint.com/

Paste your whole json there and validate.
You may find issues with your json returned.
Get that right and try again

Comment: What issues did you find in the given ressource?