# How to load cross domain url in html script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cross-domain

I want to load cross domain url html content on  my webpage. I read that it could be achieved by loading url in script and calling global callback function. My code is below-

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="response"></div>

<script>
  function myFunction (data) {
    var stringData = JSON.stringify(data)
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = stringData;
  }
</script>
<script src="http://zeenews.india.com?callback=myFunction()"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

When i run this HTML file, i get below error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

I could also see this url in front of error

```
?callback=myFunction():2
```

Please help me.

Comment: I'm guessing `zeenews.india.com` isn't actually a script file, but HTML

Comment: Yes, I want to load HTML file.

Comment: You can't do that in a script tag, if you want the HTML you'll have to use the serverside to scrape it

Comment: but they told on SO that it can be done this way

Comment: Only if it's a **javascript** file, not HTML

Comment: On this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6046008/jsonp-request-returning-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token, he writes "There is a workaround.  script tags are not subject to this restriction. This means that you can insert a script tag into the document that calls a URL. If you define a globally-accessible function in your script and tell the remote server what that function is called, the server can pass code that wraps the data to be sent in a call to that function."

Comment: And that answer is meant to be about javascript files, where one could use a valid javascript file containing a function wrapping the data to be returned, and then insert that **valid** javascript file dynamically, call the callback function, and get the data. It **does not** work with just any old websites HTML.

Comment: ok. Is there any way on this earth to get cross domain HTML content from client side under all circumstances? Thanks

Comment: No ............ you have to use a serverside script, which you *then* can call from the clientside

Comment: Well, you could make `#response` into an iFrame, that would display the site, but you still wouldn't be able to access the HTML.

Comment: I believe what you want to use is the `<iframe>` tag. It is also possible to modify the contents within the iframe you'll get with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of this tag

```
<script src="http://zeenews.india.com?callback=myFunction()"></script>
```

, since the url you entered doesn't return a javascript file. The src attribute in the `<script>` tag is for js only.

If you want to display the content of the webpage inside the *response* div tag, you should use the `<iframe>` tag inside that div, like this:

```
<div id="response">
    <iframe src="http://zeenews.india.com"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: is there anyway to get cross domain HTML through script tag? they talked about it on SO at many places

Comment: Ajax is subject to the same-origin policy, so that probably doesn't work at all.

Comment: @user609306, no there is not. Why would you even want to do something like that? Script tags are for scripts